# How does tuple pattern matching (v,w) = someFunction param_1 param_2 work?

Tags: haskell

I'm studying haskell and practicing some exercise of recursion. I came across in this expression that I really did not understand.

> `break' p xs` breaks the list `xs` at the first element that satisfies `p` and returns the pair of lists consisting of the initial sublist of `xs` containing elements that do not satisfy `p`, and the rest of the list (including the first element that satisfies `p`).

This is the signature:

```
break' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
```

It is defined by pattern matching on cases. In the fourth line, what does the expression `(v,w) = break' p xs` mean – defining a tuple with an expression? How is it possible? in this case, how are the values associated on this tuple?

```
break' p [] = ([], [])
break' p (x:xs) | p x = ([], x:xs)
                | otherwise = let (v,w) = break' p xs in (x:v, w)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider first this (on the GHCi prompt)

```
Prelude> let (a,b) = (37,'y')
```

I daresay it's clear enough what it does: assigning the tuple `(a,b)` the value `(37,'y')` is the same as assigning `a` the value `37` and `b` the value `'y'`, and indeed that's what happens here:

```
Prelude> a
37
Prelude> b
'y'
```

Now, there's nothing special to actually having written out `(37,'y')` literally on the command prompt. It's just *some tuple*, that could just as well have been defined separately:

```
Prelude> let tup = (37, 'y')
Prelude> let (a,b) = tup
```

...or it could have been the result of a function:

```
Prelude> let f x = (x, 'y')
Prelude> let (a,b) = f 37
Prelude> a
37
Prelude> b
'y'
```

To elaborate on your other example:

```
lengthAndSum :: [Float] -> (Int, Float)
lengthAndSum [] = (0,0)
lengthAndSum (x:xs) = (l+1, s+x)
 where (l,s) = lengthAndSum xs
```

then, for example

```
lengthAndSum [1,2,3]
      ≡ ( let (l,s) = lengthAndSum [2,3]
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s)
               = ( let (l',s') = lengthAndSum [3]
                   in (l'+1, s'+2) )
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s)
               = ( let (l',s')
                        = ( let (l'',s'') = lengthAndSum []
                            in (l''+1, s''+3) )
                   in (l'+1, s'+2) )
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s)
               = ( let (l',s')
                        = ( let (l'',s'') = (0,0)
                            in (l''+1, s''+3) )
                   in (l'+1, s'+2) )
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s)
               = ( let (l',s')
                        = ( let l'' = 0
                                s'' = 0
                            in (l''+1, s''+3) )
                   in (l'+1, s'+2) )
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s)
               = ( let (l',s') = (0+1, 0+3)
                   in (l'+1, s'+2) )
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ ( let (l,s) = (1+1, 3+2)
          in (l+1, s+1) )
      ≡ (2+1, 5+1)
      ≡ (3, 6)
```

Comment: @leftaroundbout your response makes sense....but   if i'had a function that coputed the length of my list and the number of total elements... for example :                                                `- lengthAndSum (x:xs) = (l+1, s+x)
--   where (l, s) = lengthAndSum xs` and i pass an array of four elements something like that [1,2,3,4 ]...in this case how the value are binded inside the tuple?

Comment: @leftaroundbout so basically my `(l,s)` have the initial condition (0,0) because in the previous line we have defined `lengthAndSum [] = (0,0)`....so when  "where" is executed first..assign that condion to my tuple value right?

Comment: Avoid thinking of “initial conditions” and what's “executed first”. Haskell has no time, Haskell variables have no state. _In the deepest recursive call_, `(l,s)` have the value `(0,0)`, yes (but those are different variables from those used in the outer recursions).

Comment: if you said me that...how could i know this matter?...this is only the case were variable are implicit about of the value or there is also other scenario?if yes there some particular topic that tell something more about that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There nothing “implicit about the value” here. It's just that Haskell allows pattern matching in any kind of assignment. You can also write `let Just p = Just 4`, resulting in `p` having the value `4` then.

Comment: i mean that the case of the (l,s)=(0,0) in the last expression is implicit i think....because there is no indication how that variable are defined at the begining....so my question is there were other scenario similar as this....because without your solution in any book i did find a response as this...

Comment: I think it's exactly your problem that you keep thinking about variables being somehow “defined at the beginning”. They aren't, never.

Comment: could you suggest me some good  book for going deeply with haskell language? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
let (v,w) = break' p xs in (x:v, w)
```

is a pattern-matching binding - `v` is bound to the first element of the result, `w` to the second.

It means (almost) the same as

```
case break' p xs of 
    (v, w) -> (x:v, w)
```

A `let` binding is lazier than a case expression with a single case.

Comment: The only difference between the two is that `let` performs lazy pattern matching, while `case` performs strict pattern matching. The exact translation would be `case ... of ~(v, w) -> ...`.

Comment: @chi I guess my mental evaluation model needs adjusting. (It's still stuck in the compiler for a different lazy language I wrote a quarter of a century ago.)

Comment: Well, my comment above is a nitpick. In most cases, this difference is irrelevant, so one easily neglects it. In the code above, it matters only if `xs` is very long or infinite, since `break` could need to scan it all before producing some output, if we use strict pattern matching.